# Overcoming platform differences in IPv6 backward compatibility

Tags: c++, cross-platform, ipv6, ipv4

The code below is my attempt at a minimal cross-platform echo server in C++.
It does what I expect, except for a platform-dependent asymmetry in the way
IP backward-compatibility is handled: on Windows, unlike the other two platforms I've tried, an IPv6 server fails to handle requests from IPv4 clients.<sup>*</sup>

To me the fact that the other platforms **can** do this (result #3 below) was an unexpected but very welcome win. It opens up some possibilities for me, provided I can get it to work on Windows too.  So my questions are: is it expected that the same thing fails on Windows (compare results #3 and #5)? And is there something I can do with the server code to get #5 to succeed?

It breaks down as follows:

Server uses IPv4 (`minimal_echo_server 8081 4`):

1. client uses IPv4 address:   server responds as expected
2. client uses IPv6 address:   connection fails<sup>**</sup> as expected

Server uses IPv6 on Ubuntu 20.04 or macOS 10.13 (`./minimal_echo_server 8081 6`):

3. client uses IPv4 address:   server responds just fine (renders the client's IP as `::ffff:` followed by an IPv4 address)
4. client uses IPv6 address:   server responds as expected

Server uses IPv6 on Windows 10 (`.\minimal_echo_server.exe 8081 6`):

5. client uses IPv4 address:   connection fails<sup>**</sup>
6. client uses IPv6 address:   server responds as expected

---

<sup>*</sup> An example of what I mean by "IPv4 client" might be the following `netcat` call:

```
nc WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ 8081 # target the server via its IPv4 address
```

in contrast to the following where the client uses IPv6:

```
nc fe80::WWWW:XXXX:YYYY:ZZZZ%en0 8081  # target the server via its IPv6 link-local address (with the client's local adapter name appended as scope)
```

---

<sup>**</sup> In both cases of "failure", the failure mode seems to depend on the client OS: a Windows 10 client will pause for a few seconds and then report "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" whereas my Linux and Darwin clients hang indefinitely as far as I can tell.

```
// Welcome to  minimal_echo_server.cpp
// This can be compiled with `cl.exe minimal_echo_server.cpp` on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019
// or with `g++ -o minimal_echo_server minimal_echo_server.cpp` on something more GNUey.
#ifdef _WIN32
#   pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")   // winsock2
#   include <winsock2.h>
#   include <ws2tcpip.h>   // for inet_pton() and inet_ntop()
#   define SOCKET_IS_VALID(S)      (S != INVALID_SOCKET)
#   define CLOSE_SOCKET closesocket
    typedef int socklen_t;
    bool InitializeSockets(void)
    {
        static bool initialized = false;
        WSADATA wsa;
        if(!initialized && WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) == 0) initialized = true;
        return initialized;
    }
#else
#   include <sys/socket.h> // for socket(), bind(), etc
#   include <arpa/inet.h>  // for sockaddr_in and inet_ntop()
#   include <unistd.h>     // close()
#   define SOCKET_IS_VALID(S)     (S >= 0)
#   define CLOSE_SOCKET close
    typedef int SOCKET;
    bool InitializeSockets(void) { return true; }
#endif

#include <string.h> 
#include <string>   
#include <sstream>  
#include <iostream> 

#define USAGE "Mandatory first argument: port number (decimal integer > 0)\n" \
              "Optional second argument: 4 or 6 to denote IP version (default: 4)\n"
    
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int maxPendingConnections = 5;
    
    struct ::sockaddr_in  serverAddress4, remoteAddress4;
    struct ::sockaddr_in6 serverAddress6, remoteAddress6;
    struct ::sockaddr * addressPtr;
    ::socklen_t addressSize;
    int domain;
    
    int port      = (argc > 1) ? ::atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
    int ipVersion = (argc > 2) ? ::atoi(argv[2]) : 4;   
    if(!port) { std::cerr << USAGE; return -1; }
    
    if(!InitializeSockets()) return -2;
    
    if(ipVersion == 4)
    {
        domain = PF_INET;
        addressPtr = (struct ::sockaddr *)&serverAddress4;
        addressSize = (::socklen_t)sizeof(serverAddress4);
        ::memset(addressPtr, 0, addressSize);
        
        serverAddress4.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddress4.sin_port = htons(port);
        serverAddress4.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    }
    else if(ipVersion == 6)
    {
        domain = PF_INET6;
        addressPtr = (struct ::sockaddr *)&serverAddress6;
        addressSize = (::socklen_t)sizeof(serverAddress6);
        ::memset(addressPtr, 0, addressSize);
        
        serverAddress6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        serverAddress6.sin6_port = htons(port);
        serverAddress6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        serverAddress6.sin6_scope_id = 0; // right?
    }
    else { std::cerr << USAGE; return -1; }
    
    SOCKET localServerSocket = ::socket(domain, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(!SOCKET_IS_VALID(localServerSocket)) return -3;
    // to keep the example minimal, I will not be explicitly closing sockets on error
    if(::bind(localServerSocket, addressPtr, addressSize) != 0) return -4;
    if(::listen(localServerSocket, maxPendingConnections) != 0) return -5;
    std::cerr << "listening on port " << port << " using IPv" << ipVersion << std::endl;
    while(true)
    {
        if(ipVersion == 4)
        {
            addressPtr = (struct ::sockaddr *)&remoteAddress4;
            addressSize = (::socklen_t)sizeof(remoteAddress4);
        }
        else if(ipVersion == 6)
        {
            addressPtr = (struct ::sockaddr *)&remoteAddress6;
            addressSize = (::socklen_t)sizeof(remoteAddress6);
        }
        SOCKET remoteConnectionSocket = ::accept(localServerSocket, addressPtr, &addressSize); 
        if(!SOCKET_IS_VALID(remoteConnectionSocket)) return -6;
        
        char buffer[128];
        std::string remoteAddressString;
        if(ipVersion == 4)
        {
            remoteAddressString = ::inet_ntop(AF_INET,  &remoteAddress4.sin_addr,  buffer, (socklen_t)sizeof(buffer)) ? buffer : "???";
        }
        else if(ipVersion == 6)
        {
            remoteAddressString = ::inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &remoteAddress6.sin6_addr, buffer, (socklen_t)sizeof(buffer)) ? buffer : "???";
            if( IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL( &remoteAddress6.sin6_addr ) )
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "%" << remoteAddress6.sin6_scope_id;
                remoteAddressString += ss.str();
            }
        }
        std::cerr << "  accepted connection from " << remoteAddressString << std::endl;
        
        while(true)
        {
            char incomingData[32];
            int bytesReceived = ::recv(remoteConnectionSocket, incomingData, sizeof(incomingData), 0);
            if(bytesReceived < 0) return -7;
            if(bytesReceived == 0) break;
            std::cerr << "  received " << bytesReceived << " bytes from " << remoteAddressString << std::endl;
            int bytesSent = ::send(remoteConnectionSocket, incomingData, bytesReceived, 0); // echo
            if(bytesSent != bytesReceived) return -8;
        }
        CLOSE_SOCKET(remoteConnectionSocket);
        std::cerr << "  closed connection from " << remoteAddressString << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; // never reached, but let's suppress the compiler warning
}
```

Comment: Just note, that [`boost` networking facilities](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io.html) should be easy to setup to hanle all of that correctly in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: IPv6 is _not_ backward-compatible with IPv4. IPv4 and IPv6 are separate, incompatible protocols, and an IPv4-only host cannot directly communicate with an IPv6-only host, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem you are running into is that under Windows, the IPV6_V6ONLY socket option is set enabled by default.  In order to get dual-stack sockets (that can work over both IPv6 and IPv4) under Windows, you need to manually disable that option for each IPv6 socket you create:

```
int v6OnlyEnabled = 0;  // we want v6-only mode disabled, which is to say we want v6-to-v4 compatibility
if (setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &v6OnlyEnabled, sizeof(v6OnlyEnabled)) != 0) printf("setsockopt() failed!?\n");
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked for me, although the one point to note is that my Windows compiler required me to cast `&v6OnlyEnabled` explicitly to `(const char *)`.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, in order to accept IPv4 clients on an IPv6 server, the server needs to use a [Dual-Stack socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/dual-stack-sockets):

> **By default, an IPv6 socket created on Windows Vista and later only operates over the IPv6 protocol.** In order to make an IPv6 socket into a dual-stack socket, the [`setsockopt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) function must be called with the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option to set this value to zero before the socket is bound to an IP address. When the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option is set to zero, a socket created for the `AF_INET6` address family can be used to send and receive packets to and from an IPv6 address or an IPv4 mapped address.